# Serving an img with bottle

Tags: python, html, web, bottle

I'm having difficulty getting an image to display in my bottle app.

My folder structure is:

```
project|
    --|views
    --|controllers
    --|static
        --|img
              --myimage
    --|models
```

On the client side I've told it to place an image with:

```
 <img href="/static/img/myimage.png" ALT="example annotation" WIDTH=500 HEIGHT=300>
```

And on the server side I've used:

```
@app.route('/static/<filename:path>')
def static(filename):
     return static_file(filename, root='static/')
```

As per the bottle docs, but I still can't get the image to load.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I usually use the following

```
import bottle
from bottle import route, run, template, BaseTemplate, static_file

app = bottle.default_app()
BaseTemplate.defaults['get_url'] = app.get_url  # reference to function

@route('/')
def index():
    return template('mytemplate')


@route('/static/<filename:path>', name='static')
def serve_static(filename):
    return static_file(filename, root='static')

run(host='localhost', port=8080)
```

Then in mytemplate I use:

```
<img src="{{ get_url('static', filename='img/myimage.png') }}" />
```